# Setup remote development Using Netbeans 12 for Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, java-me, netbeans-12

I have been trying to use Netbeans 12 IDE to remote develop on the Raspberry PI.  I have got the JDK 17 installed on the PI.  I can add a platform, attach it to the PI and test the platform, the platform manager says the test is successful.  However, when I try to change the platform in the project settings the remote platform does not appear in the drop-down list as the examples all show.  I have tried several videos and various program settings, but no success.  I have tried reading all the documentation I could but I keep going in circles.  Does anyone have any pointers to what I need to do?

Versions:

- Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.5 Updates: NetBeans IDE is
  updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2 Java: 17.0.1;
- Java       HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.1+12-LTS-39 Runtime:
- Java(TM) SE       Runtime Environment 17.0.1+12-LTS-39 System:
  Windows
- 10 version 10.0     running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

Examples:

[Setup PI for Remote Development]
https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/08/using-netbeans-remotely-deploy-projects-raspberry-pi/

[Video setting up remote PI]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXy5Ysp3yp4

[Instructions to setup Netbeans development with the PI]
https://www.instructables.com/Efficient-Development-of-Java-for-the-Raspberry-Pi

[Setting up Java ME on Raspberry PI]
https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.2/MEEPG.pdf

Images:

[Java Plataform Manager]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFPbp.png

[Successful Test]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgGzf.png

[Project Properties, Raspberry PI Not in Drop Down]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFaXl.png

Comment: Update your question with all of the following: [1] Your exact version of NetBeans. [2] The exact version of Java that you are running on NetBeans. [3] The link(s) to _"the examples"_ you are following. [4] A screen shot of your **Tools > Java Platforms** window in NetBeans. [5] Any relevant messages written to the NetBeans log file named **messages.log**, which resides in the **etc** directory under your installation of NetBeans. Show the messages in text form rather than as images.

Comment: I added the information you requested.   I did not have anything notable in the error log file.

Comment: OK. Several questions: [1] This makes no sense _"Updates: **NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2** Java: 17.0.1;"_. Is NetBeans 8.2 or NetBeans 12.5 being used? That really matters because NetBeans 8.2 does not support any Java releases > 8. [3] You state that you are using JDK 17 on Raspberry Pi, yet your screen shot shows the path to your remote _Install Folder_ includes _**jdk-8**-oracle-arm-32...._! Why? [3] One of your screen shots shows that your default Java platform on NetBeans is JDK 1.8 yet your version information states that you are using Java 17. Which is it?

Comment: Please update your question again to make the following very clear: [1] The exact version of NetBeans you are currently running. [2] The default Java platform you are currently using on NetBeans. [3] The version of Java currently installed on Raspberry Pi. that you want to use to run the applications developed on NetBeans.

Comment: Also, you're following documentation that is several years old and uses only Java 8. That's fine, but you are introducing needless complications by using Java 17 at all. You can use Java 17 on R/Pi, and you can use Java 17 in NB 12.5, but I don't know about NB 12.5 support for Java 17 as a remote platform. Also bear in mind that NB 12.5 only offers _"experimental support"_ for Java 17, so it's simpler and safer to just use Java 8 throughout: Run NetBeans 12.5 with Java 8 as its default platform, install Java 8 (instead of 17) on R/Pi, and configure your remote platform with Java 8.

Comment: I agree that NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2 Java: 17.0.1 does not make sense.  I pulled that directly from the about box.

Comment: I have not found any newer documents regarding remote development using Netbeans 12.5.  I was hoping to break new ground and see if I can get the newer version to work.   Are there different providers of Netbeans? Should I not be using Apache?

Comment: I am not seeing the different versions in the screenshots.  RPi is version  17.0.1, what I have installed on my PC is java version 17.0.1.   What I will do is downgrade to Netbeans version 8 on a VM, reinstall the OS on the PI and put java 8 on the PI.  Then try that, if I get this to work, I will try to build up from this point. I will also reach out to the Netbeans community to see if they are going to support remote development in Netbeans 12.5.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: [1] Updates belong in the question, not in the comments, and your question remains unclear. [2] Yes, in the absence of any documentation on this process using a version of Java > 8, I think that using only Java 8 in NetBeans and on R/Pi is the way to go, initially at least. As you suggest, you can try a newer version of Java once things are working, though if everything works on 8 I'd try initially upgrading to 11 rather than 17. [3] Apache is the only provider of NetBeans. Oracle are no longer involved.

Comment: One final suggestion: you could [create a bug report for your problem with NetBeans](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-6176?filter=allopenissues), but you will have to [sign up first](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Signup!default.jspa) to do that. Also, it seems a bit drastic to _"reinstall the OS on the PI"_, but I guess it can't hurt.